# El significado de "especialista en secuencias de riesgo"

Tags: significado, vocabulario-técnico

¿Qué significa ”especialista en secuencias de riesgo" en el siguiente contexto, que se trata de la siguiente descripción sobre un filme llamado "[El juego del ahorcado](https://www.elmundo.es/television/programacion-tv/peliculas/4271632_el-juego-del-ahorcado.html)"?

> "El detective Archer se une a un joven criminólogo para atrapar a un asesino en serie, cuyos crímenes parecen estar vinculados al juego del ahorcado. Christi es una joven y atractiva periodista que se unirá a la investigación. Thriller dirigido por Johnny Martin conocido más por su labor de **especialista en secuencias de riesgo** que como director."

Comment: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Maurice, sé que eres nuevo en [Spanish.se]. Creo que algunas de tus últimas preguntas casi se pueden resolver con una búsqueda simple en Google. Quizá sería mejor que hicieses el esfuerzo de buscar antes de preguntar aquí y/o que indiques que ya has hecho tal búsqueda pero que eso no aclara tus dudas (por la razón que sea). Eso ayudaría a que los usuarios pudiesen proporcionar respuestas de mayor calidad bien dirigidas a explicar lo que no entiendes. Las preguntas deben demostrar un cierto esfuerzo previo.

Comment: Hola, Diego, muchas gracias por su consejo. Dicho esto, no sé cómo responderle porque siempre hago esfuerzo antes de crear un hilo en este foro (aunque, claro, puede que a veces no lo haga correctamente). Por ejemplo, antes de crear este hilo, busqué el significado de "secuencias" en RAE, pero solo encontré esta definición relacionada a mi pregunta: "En una película, plano o serie de planos que constituyen una unidad argumental" - después de leer está definición me hizo sentir aún más confuso.

Comment: Luego hice una [búsqueda](https://www.google.com/search?q=especialista+en+secuencias+de+riesgo&oq=especialista+en+secuencias+de+riesgo&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i59l2j69i61j33.979j0j7&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) en línea, pero con mi nivel de castellano actual, no pude inducir el significado de este término (quizás sí para los nativos) con la búsqueda porque en ella solo aparece enlaces que mencionan "secuencias" sin directamente definir la palabra.

Comment: Estoy muy consciente que mis preguntas no son muy "convencionales", que podría ser un problema en los foros como este, porque este tipo de preguntas puede llegar a ser bastante "pesadas". De todas formas, les agradezco muchísimo a todos uatedes las asistencias y ayudas que me han aportado. Mientras tanto, seguiré haciendo preguntas (menos), y dejaré de hacerlas cuando llegue el momento. Saludos

Comment: Solo para añadir alguna cosa más - también he hecho otras búsquedas cómo [esta](https://www.google.com/search?q=secuencias+de+riesgo&oq=secuencias+de+riesgo&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i59l3j69i61.14075j0j7&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8), pero cada nueva búsqueda solo me hizo sentir más frustrante.

Comment: Maurice, no es necesario que indiques todo eso en la pregunta, con enlaces y todo, pero sí que expliques un poco qué te cuesta entender en esa frase (y porqué - y similar para otras preguntas). No es que tus preguntas sean "pesadas", pero sin explicar esfuerzo previos es posible que no podamos entender que no entiendes el uso de "secuencias de riesgo" y posibles respuestas solo repitan lo que ya has buscado tú por Internet (y no te sean de ayuda). Aparte, como tu nivel de español es bastante bueno, es posible que potenciales respuestas no tengan en cuenta que eres un no nativo del idioma.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus amables palabras, Diego :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cito de la [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Especialista_de_cine)

> Un **especialista de cine, doble de riesgo, stunt performer, stuntman**, o **daredevil**, es quien realiza peligrosos trucos, a menudo como profesión, los cuales son usados generalmente en el cine o la televisión

Es decir, que una de las profesiones dentro del mundo del cine es rodar secuencias peligrosas

> Los trucos vistos en cine y televisión incluyen choques de coches, caídas de grandes alturas, ser arrastrado (por ejemplo, por un caballo) y explosiones

Añado a esa lista "peleas" y otras secuencias de acción.

El tal Johnny Martin, como dice su [entrada de IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0552565/bio), es un "stuntman" (un doble de cine, alguien que hace las secuencias peligrosas en lugar del actor) que se ha movido a otras profesiones especializadas dentro del mundo del cine.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus aportaciones!